# Create a single template file for the regions in drupal 8

Tags: php, templates, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I want to have for example the footer in a single Twig-File.

These are my regions:

```
regions:
  nav: Navigation
  content: Content
  content_top: 'Content Top'
  content_bottom: 'Content Bottom'
  front_one: 'Front One'
  front_two: 'Front Two'
  footer: Footer
```

I tried to create a `region--footer.html.twig` file in the templates folder in my theme, but that doesn't worked.

Any suggestions?

Comment: please show us in greater detail what you tried and what/how it went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After fingering around the new templating in drupal 8 i succeded with:

in my `page.html.twig` at the very bottom:

```
{% if page.footer %}
  {{ page.footer }}
{% endif %}
```

Then created a  `region--footer.html.twig` with the content:

```
{% if content %}
      <div{{ attributes }}>
        {{ content }}
      </div>
{% endif %}
```

I got this snippet from `core/modules/system/templates/region.html.twig`

I think this is the correct way to override templates in Drupal 8

Comment: All the templates used by drupal are overridden by the classy theme. It is recommended that you use it as your base theme.